# Closed form for this specific induced matrix norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

Let $\|\cdot\|_{\alpha_1}$ denote the following norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$\|x\|_{\alpha_1} = \max\limits_{i=1, \ldots, n} |x_i|,$$
and let $\|\cdot\|_{\alpha_2}$ denote the following norm in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$:
$$\|y\|_{\alpha_2} = \max\limits_{i=1, \ldots, n} |y_i| + |y_{n+1}|.$$

Now, for any $(n+1)\times n$ matrix $A$ let $\|A \|_{\alpha_1, \alpha_2}$ denote the matrix norm induced by these two norms: 
$$\|A \|_{\alpha_1, \alpha_2} = \sup_{\|x\|_{\alpha_1}=1} \, \|Ax\|_{\alpha_2}.$$

It is easy for me to show that 
$$\|A \|_{\alpha_1, \alpha_2} \leq \max_{i=1, \ldots, n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{ik}| + \sum_{k=1}^p |a_{p+1,k}|.$$

But I am not sure whether this upper bound is the norm $\|A \|_{\alpha_1, \alpha_2}$ that I am looking for.

Is there a well known closed form for the induced norm of this type?

Answer (score 2):

Partition $A$ into
$$
A = \pmatrix{\hat A\\ a^T}
$$
where $\hat A$ is square and $a$ is a column-vector.  We have
$$
\|Ax\|_{\alpha_2} = \|\hat Ax\|_\infty + |a^Tx|
$$
And we are maximizing this subject to $\|x\|_\infty = 1$.  Applying the definition of the induced norm and Hölder, we have
$$
\|Ax\| = \|\hat Ax\|_\infty + |a^Tx| \leq \|\hat A\|_\infty \|x\|_\infty + \|a^T\|_\infty \|x\|_\infty
$$
And with $\|a^T\|_\infty = \|a\|_1$, this is exactly the inequality that you got.  However, this will not generally give us a tight upper bound, since we can't necessarily attain both maxima simultaneously.  For example, with
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&-1\\1&1}
$$
we indeed have $\|A\|_{\alpha_2} \leq 2+2 = 4$.  However, we find 
$$
\max_{|x_1|,|x_2| \leq 1} |x_1 - x_2| + |x_1 + x_2| = \\
\max_{0\leq x_2 < x_1 \leq 1} |x_1 - x_2| + |x_1 + x_2| = \\
\max_{0\leq x_2 < x_1 \leq 1} 2x_1 = 2
$$
I am not aware of any closed form for the desired matrix norm.

Comment: Of course, we also have the lower bound
$$
\min\{\|Ax\|_\infty, \|a\|_1\}
$$